# Create built-in pages without creating actual pages

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, pages, page-template

For example:

`site.com/contact` (or `site.com/?page=contact` if not using permalinks)

when someone goes to that page I want to load a theme template, like `page-contact.php`

But I don't want to create a page in the dashboard for this work. How can I do this internally, within functions.php ?

I know it's possible because that bbpress plugin does it somehow for the /users/ pages, which are not standard wordpress pages...

Answer (score 7):

This is the technique I'm using on a site right now. It involves registering a query var for "template", and registering an endpoint called `/contact`, which rewrites internally to `?template=contact`. Then you just check for that query variable at the template_redirect hook, and if its present, include the page template you want to load and exit.

```
/* Add a query var for template select, and and endpoint that sets that query var */
add_action( 'init', 'wpse22543_rewrite_system' );

function wpse22543_rewrite_system() {
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'template' );   
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'contact', EP_ROOT );
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule(  '^/contact/?$', 
                            'index.php?template=contact', 'bottom' );
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }


/* Handle template redirect according the template being queried. */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse22543_select_template' );

function wpse22543_select_template() {
    global $wp;
    $template = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'template', $template ) && 
        'contact' == $template['template'] ) {
        /* Make sure to set the 404 flag to false, and redirect 
               to the contact page template. */
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set( 'is_404', false );
        include( get_stylesheet_directory().'/contact.php' );
        exit;
        }
    }
```

This will serve up your contact.php file for any requests for ?template=contact or /contact.

There's probably a quicker way of doing it, but this works. Here's a more thorough tutorial: [Create Fake Pages in WordPress](http://betterwp.net/98-wordpress-create-fake-pages/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just as you said. It is built into the template hierarchy of Wordpress since 2.9.

If you have a page named Contact, create a page template called page-contact.php which is different than page.php. And voila, it works.

From WP documentation.

> Templates by page-ID or page-Slug
>
> You can use different archives "page",
>   with ID or slug in your name. Only
>   Available with Version 2.9.
>
> examples:
>
> ```
> page-{id}.php
> page-{slug}.php
> ```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: You could then put anything you want into that page-contact.php, including static HTML.